# Custom 401 Page - 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I cannot for the life of me work out why this isn't working.
I have 2 apache directives. My entire site should require authentication except for the login page which everyone should be able to access. When I do this I get the error below:

> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
>
> Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My Apache Config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot C:/htdocs/example
  <Directory "C:/htdocs/example">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthName "Example"
    AuthType SSPI
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIOfferSSPI On
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    SSPIPerRequestAuth On
    require valid-user
    ErrorDocument 401 /login/alternate
  </Directory>
  <Location /login>
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allow `/login/alternate` as well without a login before it will work properly

```
<Location /login/alternate>
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
</Location>
```